# Please recommend UI library for an embedded linux gaming device

Tags: linux, user-interface, game-development, embedded-systems

I am working on a gaming platform that will be running on a device powered by the embedded Linux.

Now I need to implement a UI, where user can configure settings for the device, select game to play and so on.

I am looking for an UI library that allows small memory footprint and CPU limited usage, yet making possible eye-candy widgets.

Any language is OK, ideally Python or C++.

Extra points if this library is not overly complicated.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! A library for what language? Python? C++? Qt? Any concerns toward the license?

Comment: Any language can work. License should not force me to open source my source codes.

Comment: Just to give us an idea, what CPU and what memory is in your device?